# VB.net how to return cell data from column and row of datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, row, cell

I have a WPF datagrid currently populated with data.

I would like to return the cell value of the cell which the user click on, when the datagrid is in full row select mode.

At the moment I am able to return the row and column of the cell which the user select but I am not sure how to return the actual cell value.

Here is my VB code.

```
Private Sub WaterfallDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs) Handles WaterfallDataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged

        'return the column of the cell of the datagrid
        textBox1.Text = WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex

        'return the row of the cell of the datagrid
        textBox2.Text = WaterfallDataGrid.Items.IndexOf(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentItem)

        'how do i return the value of the cell itself?
        'textBox3.Text = ??

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the SelectedCellsChangedEvent is fired, you get the SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs to work with. This object has a property called **AddedCells**. When the user clicks the cell, the whole row is selected, so the whole row is contained in **AddedCells**. You already know the column number from your code, so this should work:

```
Private Sub WaterfallDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs) Handles WaterfallDataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged

    textBox3.Text = e.AddedCells(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex).Item(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)

End Sub
```

Source:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.selectedcellschangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:
The event will only fire when a cell in a new row is selected. If you select a cell in the same row, nothing will happen. To always get the current cell, you should register the CurrentCellChanged event in your DataGrid.

Add the CurrentCellChanged event to your xaml:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="WaterfallDataGrid" CurrentCellChanged="WaterfallDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged" />
```

And this to your codebehind:

```
Private Sub WaterfallDataGrid_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    textBox3.Text = WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Item(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Code compiles but throws a runtime error due to the conversion from type 'DataRowView' to type 'String'. I added a .ToString to the rear of that statement. It does not throw a runtime error but it returns something like: 
"System.Data.DataRowView". Any ideas?

Comment: What data is in the datagrid? How do you insert the data?

Comment: The datagrid has been previously populated by a code similar to this:  dt2.Rows.Add("Final Derated Cable Ampacity (A)",
        GlobalVariables.DeratedCCC(1),
        GlobalVariables.DeratedCCC(2),
        GlobalVariables.DeratedCCC(3),
        )

        CableValuesDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView

Comment: Can you get the .Item property from that DataRowView? Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry...I tried my best to understand those VB codes but I could not figure out what I need to do. Some help please.

Comment: textBox3.Text = e.AddedCells(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex).Item(WaterfallDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex)

Comment: Thanks Pie. That code works...but only if I am selecting the cell between Rows. Say I move from R1C1 to R2C1. If I first select the sell R1C1 and then hit R1C2, the data did not get picked up.